# RxAndroidBle "LOCATION_PERMISSION_MISSING"

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions, android-bluetooth

Доброго времени суток :D Подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего может возникать ошибка "**LOCATION_PERMISSION_MISSING**", при вызове метода `scanBleDevices`? Уже час ломаю голову не чего не могу придумать.

Фрагмент кода :

```
import com.polidea.rxandroidble.RxBleClient;
import com.polidea.rxandroidble.RxBleScanResult;
import rx.Observable;

/**
 * Created by johny on 02.01.2017.
 */
public class bluetooth_controler {

    public void rxScan(RxBleClient client){

        Observable<RxBleScanResult> scanSubscription = client.scanBleDevices();

    }

}
```

P.S. В гугле тщательно поискал, пусто.

P.S.S. Пробовал добавить в манифест `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: А что в доке к либе на сей счёт сказано? А не на 6-ой ли оси тестите с незапрошенными в рантайме разрешениями?

Comment: ЮрийСПб, в доке тупо указаны огрызки примеров и без всяких пояснений (https://www.polidea.com/blog/RxAndroidBLE_the_most_Simple_way_to_code_Bluetooth_Low_Energy_devices/) и да я тестирую на шестёрке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что сканирование окружающих устройств может дать информацию о местоположении устройства. Поэтому начиная с Android 6.0 (API level 23) для этого необходимо запросить `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` или `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`. Это касается как списка bluetooth устройств, так и MAC адресов и SSID WiFi сетей.

Одновременно с этим в 6.0 появились runtime permissions: пермишены, попавшие в группу [опасных (dangerous)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#perm-groups), нужно не только указать в `AndroidManifest.xml`, но и запросить у пользователя явно. Доступ к местоположению входит в их число. Подробнее об этом написано в [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Для эксперементов на этапе разработки можете в Settings в списке приложений найти ваше, зайти в раздел Permissions, и там руками дать разрешение.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно вот этому [треду на gitHube](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/issues/10) требуются таки разрешения на местоположение. И сама либа их из коробки не проверяет. Т.е. вам надо, с 6 версии андроида запрашивать их самостоятельно у юзера. После того как он даст разрешение можно использовать саму либу

Comment: А в чём взаимосвязь между GPS и Bluetooth? 0_о

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, насколько я понял некоторые девайсы имеют инфу о местоположении и поэтому юзер должен знать, что какая-то инфа о местоположении будет использоваться